# Create new variables from string value (VBA)

Tags: vba

I would like to create a new variable from a strings value. The name of the variable should be the value from the string. 
Example :
I have an array that contains :

ParamList(1) = AA

ParamList(2) = BB

ParamList(3) = CC

From this list the following variables need to be created :

AA

BB

CC

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can you describe how you're trying to use this?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a better case for simple iteration over the array?

Comment: This is part a much bigger dynamic tool. The string values are used to search for certain columns in different files, the variable created from the string value will hold the column number. This will be used then to process the data from the different files. The amount of strings and values of them are different every time.

Comment: Solution here is to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to capture the variables' "names" (as keys) and values.

Comment: Why would you need such???

Answer (score 0):

Looking round online the consensus seems to be that VBA does not support dynamic naming of variabales and most answers seem to suggest using arrays instead as @DavidZemens has above e.g. [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524440-dynamic-variable-name-visual-basic-applications.html).

If you cannot achieve what you want to using arrays then it may be worth investigating [Evaluate](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372) or [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to see if they can offer enough flexibility to make this work another way.